# A Start Job is Running for Network Manager Wait Online ( no limit )

Tags: boot, networkmanager

in **RHEL 8.8**, and I've seen this in RHEL 7.9, when booting my RHEL linux pc at work, which has a full network security including network switch/router MAC filtering, that linux does not get DHCP served an IP immediately it takes 20+ seconds for the network to provide it sometimes, once it does then everything is fine.  When doing work and I am rebooting the pc numerous time, this delay in linux (systemd ?) becomes a nuisance, sometimes it will take ~30 seconds before getting past this point in the verbose boot screen.  Is there a way to get rid of this pause during boot?

The boot is always successful, but I suspect if something else were to change that my pc would never boot.  That would be a problem.  I would rather it boot and not have network connection, versus sitting at the boot screen counting away with no limit.

```
# here is what I see at the boot screen
# is there a way to not see this and not be delayed by it?

A start job is running for Network Manager Wait Online (15s / no limit)
```